# How to check List type alias in Python?

Tags: python, list, types, python-3.7

```
x: List[int]
```

If I have code like above, which is declaring an object `x` with List with an explicit type `int` using Python's `typing` library, is there a way that I can find out that this object `x` is an integer type? Not just a list type.

I know if I do `type(x)` it'll give `<class 'list'>`, but doesn't say it's an integer type list. I also tried `type(x[0])` and it gave `<class 'NoneType'>`, which makes sense that it's an empty list. I can't initialize the first element with integer type value (i.e. `x: List[int] = [0]`) or something as it is assigning an arbitrary value to the list, which may cause an issue if we do not handle (override to the proper value) it properly and it's risky (for me at least).

This is an important feature that I have to have in the team project that I am working on. Can anyone with a good Python knowledge help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just to need to use mypy. If you have any type errors, mypy will tell you. Otherwise everything is OK. You possibly never don't need to check types in runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Python is a dynamically typed language, so even with `type` hinting, the `type` itself is not enforced.  Therefore `List[int]` does not guarantee any elements added to `x` is an `int` type.

If you do need to ensure the `type` is `int`, you will need to manually check it:

```
if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in x):
    # code things for when x is indeed a list of all ints
else:
    # code things for when x is not all int
```

You might also consider doing an `assert` instead:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, '3']
>>> assert all(isinstance(i, int) for i in x), 'Values must be all int type!'

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#249>", line 1, in <module>
        assert all(isinstance(i, int) for i in x), 'Values must be all int type!'
    AssertionError: Values must be all int type!
```

If you have multiple `List[...]` that you want to check for, you can make your own checker function:

```
def validate(lst: list, dtype):
    return all(isinstance(i, dtype) for i in lst)

>>> validate([1, 2, '3'], int):
>>> False

>>> validate(['a', 'b', 'c'], str):
>>> True
```